# Video output in ruby-mingw32 + gstreamer on Windows

Tags: ruby, mingw, mingw32, gstreamer

I have a trouble with video output in ruby+gstreamer on Windows XP.

Before I used "**dshowvideosink**" in ruby1.86 (not mingw32) with gstreamer 0.1, which was installed separately. All were fine.

Now I need ruby1.9 (or higher) and any gstreamer.
I've tried to install **ruby1.9.3-mingw32** and **ruby2.0.0-mingw32**.
Also I installed gstreamer via command "gem.bat install gstreamer" in both case.
But there is no "dshowvideosink" in new version ruby+gstreamer!!!

I investigate a problem by the example:

```rb
require 'gtk2'
require 'gst'

def os_family
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
    when /ix/i, /ux/i, /gnu/i, /sysv/i, /solaris/i, /sunos/i, /bsd/i
      'unix'
    when /win/i, /ming/i
      'windows'
    else
      'other'
  end
end

Gst.init

pipeline = Gst::Pipeline.new('pipeline1')
videosrc = Gst::ElementFactory.make('videotestsrc', 'videosrc1')
videoconvert = Gst::ElementFactory.make('autovideoconvert', 'videoconvert1')
videosink = Gst::ElementFactory.make('autovideosink', 'videosink1');

pipeline.add(videosrc, videoconvert, videosink)
videosrc >> videoconvert >> videosink

window = Gtk::Window.new('Video test')
window.signal_connect("destroy") { pipeline.stop; Gtk.main_quit }
window.set_default_size(320, 240)
window.show_all

pipeline.bus.add_watch do |bus, message|
  if (message and message.structure and message.structure.name \
  and (message.structure.name == 'prepare-xwindow-id'))
    Gdk::Threads.synchronize do
      Gdk::Display.default.sync
      if not window.destroyed? and window.window
        win_id = nil
        if os_family=='windows'
          win_id = window.window.handle
        else
          win_id = window.window.xid
        end
        imagesink = message.src
        imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", true)
        imagesink.set_xwindow_id(win_id)
      end
    end
  end
  true
end

pipeline.play
Gtk.main
```

It works nice on Linux (Lubuntu), but doesn't work on Windows (XP)!

Suggest me please:
1) how can I reanimate "dshowvideosink" in ruby 1.9 or 2.0?
2) what component can I use instead of "dshowvideosink" on Windows?
3) how I can [re]install gstreamer or its plugins separately from ruby-mingw32 (without gem)?

Answer (score 0):

In reply to 2:
For windows you should be using d3dvideosink.

Comment: There is no such element in default gstreamer in ruby.

Comment: I apologies I've been using the C# build for the past month or so and completely forgot it wasn't in Ruby

Comment: Remarkably, it works fine in Ruby1.86, but doesn't work ("from the box") in Ruby1.93.